# web scraping a site without direct access

Tags: python

any help is appreciated in advance.

deal is i have been trying scrape data from this website(https://www.mptax.mp.gov.in/mpvatweb/leftMenu.do),but direct access to the website is not possible.Rather then data i need,i am getting invalid access.To access the website i must go to (https://www.mptax.mp.gov.in/mpvatweb/index.jsp) and then click on 'dealer search' from  dropdown menu while hovering over dealer information.
I am looking for solution in Python,
Here's something i tried.I have just started web scraping:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as request:

    MAIN="https://www.mptax.mp.gov.in/mpvatweb/leftMenu.do"
    INITIAL="https://www.mptax.mp.gov.in/mpvatweb/"

    page=request.get(INITIAL)
    jsession=page.cookies["JSESSIONID"]
    print(jsession)
    print(page.headers)

    result=request.post(INITIAL,headers={"Cookie":"JSESSIONID="+jsession+"; zoomType=0","Referer":INITIAL})
    
    page1=request.get(MAIN,headers={"Referer":INITIAL})
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page1.content,'html.parser')

    data=soup.find_all("tr",class_="whitepapartd1")

    print(data)
```

Deal is i want to scrape data about firm's based on their firm name.

Comment: You can use `Selenium` for first login page then use `bs` for scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind using a browser?

You can use a browser and access the link at xpath (//*[@id="dropmenudiv"]/a[1]).

You might have to download and put chromedriver in the mentioned directory if you haven't used chromedriver before. You can also use selenium + phantomjs if you want to do headless browsing (without the browser opening up each time).

```
from selenium import webdriver
xpath = "//*[@id="dropmenudiv"]/a[1]"
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
browser.set_window_size(1120,550)
browser.get('https://www.mptax.mp.gov.in/mpvatweb')
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="dropmenudiv"]/a[1]")
link.click()
url = browser.current_url
```

Comment: thanks ,but is it possible to do same using request package,because i have been trying to do it with it and couldn't succeed.Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, i tried but keep getting error element not found,
I even tried using find_element_by_css_selector -same error.Thanks for the trouble in advance

Comment: Did you try to hover over the "//*[@id="mainsection"]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/a" element and then making the webdriver wait till it finds the "//*[@id="dropmenudiv"]/a[1]" element and then click?
Editing the main answer to help you hover.

Comment: yes,that's exactly what i did,and it's working and i have already uploaded the working code

Answer (score 0):

thanks for telling me a way @Arnav and @Arman ,so here's the final code:

```
from selenium import webdriver #to work with website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #to scrap data
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains #to initiate hovering
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #to input value

PROXY = "10.3.100.207:8080" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

#ask for input
company_name=input("tell the company name")

#import website
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get("https://www.mptax.mp.gov.in/mpvatweb/")

#perform hovering to show hovering
element_to_hover_over = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#mainsection > form:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)")

hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()

#click on dealer search from dropdown menu
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#dropmenudiv > a:nth-child(1)").click()

#we are now on the leftmenu page

#click on radio button
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#byName").click()

#input company name
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#showNameField > td:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)")
inputElement.send_keys(company_name)

#submit form
inputElement.submit() 

#now we are on dealerssearch page

#scrap data
soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"lxml")

#get the list of values we need
list=soup.find_all('td',class_="tdBlackBorder")

#check length of 'list' and on that basis decide what to print 
if(len(list)!=0):
    #company name at index=9
    #tin no. at index=10
    #registration status at index=11
    #circle name at index=15

    #store the values
    name=list[9].get_text()
    tin=list[10].get_text()
    status=list[11].get_text()
    circle=list[15].get_text()

    #make dictionary
    Company_Details={"TIN":tin ,"Firm name":name ,"Circle_Name":circle, "Registration_Status":status}

    print(Company_Details)
else:
    Company_Details={"VAT RC No":"Not found in database"}

    print(Company_Details)

#close the chrome 
browser.stop_client()
browser.close()
browser.quit()
```